# Convert .txt file to .csv , where each line goes to a new column and each paragraph goes to a new row

Tags: python, database, csv, dataset, data-analysis

I am relatively new in dealing with txt and json datasets. I have a dialogue dataset in a txt file and i want to convert it into a csv file with each new line converted into a column. and when the next dialog starts (next paragraph), it starts with a new row. so i get data in format of

```
Header = ['Q1' , 'A1' , 'Q2' , 'A2' .......]
```

here is the data for reference (this file is in txt format) :
[dialog data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuvpA.png)

```
1 hello hello what can i help you with today
2 may i have a table in a moderate price range for two in rome with italian cuisine i'm on it
3 <SILENCE> ok let me look into some options for you
4 <SILENCE> api_call italian rome two moderate

1 hi    hello what can i help you with today
2 can you make a restaurant reservation in a expensive price range with british cuisine in rome for eight people    i'm on it
3 <SILENCE> ok let me look into some options for you
4 <SILENCE> api_call british rome eight expensive

1 hi    hello what can i help you with today
2 may i have a table in london with spanish cuisine i'm on it
3 <SILENCE> how many people would be in your party
4 we will be six    which price range are looking for
5 i am looking for a moderate restaurant    ok let me look into some options for you
6 <SILENCE> api_call spanish london six moderate
```

Comment: I'm unsure of what the output should be, do you want each lone of text squashed into a line of csv, and then the paragraph breaks converted into rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSV file is a list of strings separated by commas, with newlines (`\n`) separating the rows.

Due to this simplistic layout, it is often not suitable for containing strings that may contain commas within them, for instance dialogue.

That being said, with your input file, it is possible to use regex to replace any single newlines with a comma, which effectively does the "each new line converted into a column, each new paragraph a new row" requirement.

```py
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r') as reader:
    text = reader.read()

text = re.sub(r"(...)\n", r"\1,", text)
print(text)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as writer:
    writer.write(text)
```

Working example [here](https://replit.com/@LukeStorry/67990813#main.py).

Comment: The '.\n' is omitting the last letter of the sentence too. if i dont use the dot, it registers the new paragraph as a comma too. @luke-storry

Comment: ah yeah, just updated it to capture those letters  `()` and add them into the substitution with `\1`